# Javascript: How to single-step site initialization?

Tags: javascript, debugging, initialization, firebug

Short background: I'm pretty new to Javascript and currently interested in customizing third-party websites to my needs — i.e. write scripts for Greasemonkey and the like. Often those sites are bloated with libraries like Jquery, Bootstrap, etc. which makes it even harder to figure out how exactly they work.

When I analyze a new website and want to know what code gets executed, I can use Firebug to create breakpoints or watchpoints and then single-step through the code. However, this does not work for code that already runs while/when the website first loads. How can I single-step through this part? Basically I'm looking for a way to set a breakpoint to the point before even the first Javascript code is executed.

If there are better tools for this than Firebug I'm all open for suggestions. Please keep in mind that I do not control the website, so changing the site's code is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's enough for you to stop at the load event of the page (normally some code gets executed before that event), you can do the following:

1. Switch to the *HTML* panel and there to the *Events* side panel.
2. Scroll down to the section saying *Other listeners for Window*
3. Right-click the function under the 'load' event (might be one with an arrow besides it) and choose *Set Breakpoint* from the context menu.

   *Note: There might be a 'DOMContentLoaded' event handler, which is called before the 'load' event. So, if that exists, set the breakpoint at that function.*
4. Reload the page.

Here's a screenshot of that menu:
[image: Setting a breakpoint at the 'load' event]

As mentioned above, normally some code is already executed before the 'load' event is fired, like libraries getting loaded or some global variables being initialized. Though as far as I know, there is no option in Firebug (or other browser developer tools) to stop the script execution at the very first executed JavaScript statement.
But it's normally still quite easy to set a breakpoint at that line. It just requires some manual searching:

1. Inside the *Script* panel select the first script called *Inline* from the [*Script Location Menu*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Script_Location_Menu) (the third toolbar button from the left).
2. Search for the first JavaScript line, or, if there is no inline JavaScript, select the script within the first `<script>` element from the *Script Location Menu*.
3. Set a breakpoint at the first line of the script.
4. Reload the page.